# Implementing Fermat factorisation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, factorization

I have been set this question for homework:

> Another approach to factoring was used by Fermat in 1643. It is more
>   suited to finding large factors than small ones. Assume n is an odd
>   number and that n = u × v. It follows that n = x^2 − y^2 , where x = (u
>   + v)/2 and y = (v − u)/2 are both whole numbers (why?). Fermat’s method consists of systematically searching for the smallest value of
>   x for which there is a y such that x^2 − y^2 = n and 0 ≤ y < x.
>
> Exercise 11. What is the smallest possible value of x, that is, the
>   value we should begin the search with? Suppose that at some stage the
>   search has been narrowed to x ≥ p and y ≥ q. Let r = p^2 − q^2 − n. If
>   r = 0, then we are done. If r < 0, how should we change p or q? And
>   how do we change r to maintain r = p^2 − q^2 − n? And what if r > 0?
>   Why is this method guaranteed to terminate for all odd n? Design a
>   function search so that search p q r carries out the search. Hence
>   design a function fermat for returning two factors of a given odd
>   number.

This is what I have so far:

```
type Factors = (Integer, Integer)
search :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Factors
search n p q r
   | r == 0    = (p-q,p+q)
   | r < 0     = search n a b c
   | otherwise = search n d b e
      where a = p+1 ; b = isqrt (q*q+2*(p-1)+1) ; c = (a*a-b*b-n) ;
             d = p-1 ; e = (d*d-b*b-n)

isqrt :: Integer -> Integer
isqrt = truncate . sqrt . fromInteger

fermat :: Integer -> Factors
fermat n
  | n == 0    = (0,0)
  | otherwise = search n p q r 
    where p = isqrt(n) ; q = 1 ; r = (p*p-q*q-n)
```

This works for some numbers like 33 (I get (3,11) as expected) but not for others like 99 (I get (1,99) instead of (9,11)). I think I need to use something different for the initial value of q. Some hints would be appreciated.

I have tried changing the initial value of q to `isqrt( abs(p*p-n))`, but this still gives 99 to be (3, 33) which isn't right.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? (As in, what output do you get, and what do you expect?)

Comment: Hint: consider 121 (or 169) for example. Another hint: `p` should never decrease.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel Fischer suggested in his hint, the search starts at the square root and increases. Here's the algorithm, which I will leave to you to translate to Haskell:

```
function fermat(n)
    s = floor(sqrt(n))
    u, v, r = 2*s+1, 1, s*s-n
    repeat
        if r > 0 then v, r = v+2, r-v
        else if r < 0 then u, r = u+2, r+u
        else return (u+v-2)/2, (u-v)/2
```

Note that the two factors returned by this algorithm may or may not be prime; if the return values are *n* and 1, then the input *n* is prime. I discuss this algorithm at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2009/05/19/fermats-method/). Note that Fermat's algorithm is one of the worst ways to find the factors of a number; even trial division is usually quicker, except for the case where *n* is a semi-prime with two factors of similar magnitude.